# Spring Boot Microservice - 401 Authorized Issue in my service

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices, keycloak

I have a problem about accessing any request url in UserController of UserService.

I used Keycloak running in docker through this command

```
docker run -p 8181:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2 start-dev
```

When I call any method of UserController like `http://localhost:9000/api/v1/users/signup` or `http://localhost:9000/USER-SERVICE/api/v1/users/signup`, I get 401 Authorized error.

How can I fix it? Where is the problem in Userservice of Api Gateway ?

Here is my project link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices)

Comment: Perhaps this similar sample can help: https://github.com/timtebeek/spring-security-samples/tree/main/spring-cloud-gateway-oidc-tokenrelay

Comment: In your [`application.properties`](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices/blob/master/user-service/src/main/resources/application.properties#L17), you configured keycloak on port `8080`. In your [`docker-compose.yml`](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L27), however, you configured keycloak to run on local port `8181`.

Comment: Which application.properties do I configure keycloak on port 8080?

Comment: @Tim Is it possible to look through my link if you don't mind?

Comment: @Turing85  Is it possible to look through my link if you don't mind?

Comment: All services that use keycloak have to contact keycloak on the port that it is available on. So if you expose keycloak on `localhost:8181`, all services must contact it through `localhost:8181`.